# Err:11 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian una Release 404 Not Found [IP: 52.84.70.25 443]

Tags: linux, linux-mint

Uso linux-mint
Estoy intentando instalar docker.
he seguido los pasos:

```sh
sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker.io containerd runc
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    gnupg \
    lsb-release
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg
echo \
  "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian \
  $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
```

Pero en el momento de ejecutar :  `sudo apt-get update`
Me sale el error que he puesto arriba.

No tiene casi información así que supongo que la solución es muy obvia pero para mi no.
Estoy intentando instalar docker.
Solo he cortado y pegado, entiendo donde me he podido equivocar.

Comment: Modificaste algo antes de correr ese comando? Si es así, por favor ve a [edit] la pregunta e incluye el contenido del archivo que cambiaste.

Comment: Solo corte y pegue los pasos.
Al principio me equivoque seguí los pasos para ubuntu hasta que me di cuenta de que no era el mimo proceso para linux mint. Luego retome el proceso para linux-mint

Comment: Seguimos sin saber qué pasos eran. Si sale ESE error con ESE comando, algo hiciste antes y si no nos cuentas, es imposible ayudar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como viste, tienes que usar repos Ubuntu-based y no los debian-based (misma gestión de paquetes, nombres de releases diferentes).

Prueba borrando el archivo `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list` (con sudo) y luego añade el repo correcto usando algo como

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu
 bionic stable"
```

NOTA: Revisa que `bionic` corresponde a tu versión! Eso es lo que `lsb_release` te debería decir (y por eso se usa en el comando que probaste)

Ahí ya deberías poder hacer `sudo apt update` y luego `sudo apt install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io`

PD. `apt-get` está vieeejo ;)

Comment: Pfff. Me ha pasado eso tantas veces en frente de mis compañeros...

Comment: La voy a dar por buena ya (aunque no funcionase me ha dado un hilo del que ir tirando) pero voy a tardar un poco en comprobar si realmente funciona.